# Magento 2 : Acl admin controller

Tags: magento2, admin-controller, acl

I can see below code in file

```
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

/**
 * Abstract assignment controller
 */
abstract class Assignment extends Action
{
    /**
     * Authorization level of a basic admin session
     *
     * @see _isAllowed()
     */
    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Vendor_Catalog::import_product_category_assignment';
}
```

This class is extended by controller

class Index extends Assignment

I am not sure what's the use of "`const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Vendor_Catalog::import_product_category_assignment';`" there

Comment: Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated ?

Answer (score 1):

Function _isAllowed() was implemented on every action to defined the permission to run the action.

In _isAllowed() it's gonna use the const ADMIN_RESOURCE which be defined on your controller.

To understand the tag Vendor_Catalog::import_product_category_assignment. This is a resource which be defined on etc/acl.xml current module

See
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ext-best-practices/tutorials/create-access-control-list-rule.html

For multiple resources you could add

```
/**
 * @return bool
 */
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Foo_Bar::foo_bar') && $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Bar_Foo::bar_foo');
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer i have extended this class in my multiple controllers should i add "const ADMIN_RESOURCE ="  for that too in same file ?
i mean multiple admin_resource in same file?

Comment: @devhs I've updated the answer related to multiple resources

Comment: Thankyou for the answer